# How to subtract a particular value from array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am creating a program using JavaScript while a clicking of button it will select a seat and change its background color to green and at the same time the button value will be added to the text field and will toggle accordingly.

Issue: I am adding all the value to the text field using an array, which is successful but during toggling it cannot able to subtract the particular clicking button value from array.

Here I cannot able to use jQuery because this page is coming from a ajax-page load.

```
// JavaScript Document

var Cur_id;
var Cur_val;

function setId(id, value) {
    Cur_id = id;
    Cur_val = value;
    var SeatVal = document.getElementById(id);
    if (SeatVal.style.backgroundImage == "") {
        SeatVal.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'themes/frontend/images/greenseat.png\')";
        var txbtElementSeat = new Array(document.getElementById("selectedseat").value += Cur_val + ",");
    } else if (SeatVal.style.backgroundImage == 'url("themes/frontend/images/greenseat.png")') {
        SeatVal.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'themes/frontend/images/seat.png\')";
        var txbtElementSeatnbg = document.getElementById("selectedseat").value;
        removeSeat(txbtElementSeatnbg, Cur_val);

        function removeSeat(txbtElementSeatnbg, value) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= txbtElementSeatnbg.length; i++) {
                if (txbtElementSeatnbg[i] == value) {
                    txbtElementSeatnbg.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (SeatVal.style.backgroundImage == 'url("themes/frontend/images/seat.png")') {
        SeatVal.style.backgroundImage = "url(\'themes/frontend/images/greenseat.png\')";
        var txbtElementseatnb = document.getElementById("selectedseat").value += Cur_val + ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose with using `this` in this line: `removeSeat(this.txbtElementSeatnbg, this.Cur_val);`?

Comment: because it will provide the current value of array and current value of button.

Comment: What @Niko meant was: What is the `this` value in your function? What will those properties contain? Please notice that `this` is not a reference to local variables in JavaScript.

Comment: it means when i will click a button , the role of this operator is it will take the current value and current id.

Comment: sorry,if this is not a reference to local variables then i had done it worngly.

Comment: That's a whole lot of code. Perhaps a jsFiddle would be a good idea.

Comment: Check out my answer, I added a working example. let me know if is that what you need

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue seems to be that you try to save an array into a textfield. That will actually work, but will convert the array to a string representation.

`var a = document.getElementById('selectedseat').value;` therefore loads the string representation of the array into a variable "a", not the array itself!

Why don't you use a variable in the outer context (not the local function scope of setId()!) to hold the array? Maybe somewhat like this:

```
// Create a variable for the array!
var selectedSeats = new Array();

// Build a function that will update the textfield.
// Call this, whenever the array gets changed!
function updateListOfSelectedSeats() {
    document.getElementById('selectedseat').value = selectedSeats.join(',');
}

// Removes a seat from the list of selected seats
function removeSeatFromList(seat) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedSeats.length; i++) {
        if (selectedSeats[i] == seat) {
            selectedSeats.splice(i, 1);
            updateListOfSelectedSeats();
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Now the function that reacts to clicks on a seat
function setId(id, value) {
    var Seat = document.getElementById(id);

    switch (Seat.style.backgroundImage) {
        case 'url("themes/frontend/images/greenseat.png")':
            // Seat is already selected and needs to be deselected
            Seat.style.backgroundImage = 'url("themes/frontend/images/seat.png")';
            removeSeatFromList(value);
            break;

        case '':
        case 'url("themes/frontend/images/seat.png")':
            // Seat is empty, select it!
            Seat.style.backgroundImage = 'url("themes/frontend/images/greenseat.png")';
            selectedSeats.push(value);
            updateListOfSelectedSeats();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the seat from the list use this

```
//remove seat from list
function removeSeat(seatListElm, seatValue) {
    var arr=seatListElm.value.split(',');

     var p=arr.indexOf(seatValue);
     if(p!=-1){
         arr.splice(p, 1);
         seatListElm.value=arr.join(',');
     }
}
```

seatListElm would be the element that hold `"b5,c7,d5,c2"`
seatValue would be something like this `"c7"`

---

Working demo code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/7J8vj/)

[image: JSFiddle exemple]